# Input and type issue

Tags: c++

I begin with Stroustrup's [Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++](http://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html) and I came accross the first issue. To make long story short, suppose we have the following chunk of code:

```
int main() {
  cout << "Enter your first name and age:\n";
  string first_name = "???";
  int age = -1;
  cin >> first_name >> age;
  cout << "Hello, " << first_name << " (age " << age << ")\n";
}
```

Following the book the input `22 Carlos` should output:

```
Hello, 22 (age -1)
```

but I get:

```
Hello, 22 (age 0)
```

I have no idea what's wrong. Any idea or pointer?

Comment: use a debugger, it will tell you

Comment: Are you sure the book had that code paired with that input?

Comment: I think you are mistaken. [Running your code](http://ideone.com/Pt2ByZ) yields the output `Hello, Carlos (age 22)`

Comment: it's the correct output according to the source and input, your are reading `first_name, age`, in that order, for that you read `22` as `firstname` and try to read `Carlos` as `age` and fail to read an int, setting the default value (0).

Comment: @Andrej The code should not behave as you describe, and given what I know about the author, I'd guess you misread something, rather than the book being in error.

Comment: @Cyber No, the author gives `22 Carlos` as example.

Comment: @Andrej ... are you running the code from a place that accepts input??? standard input??? if you run if from an online compiler (like ideone.com), the input will give void, and you will get whatever results you are describing... please, compile and run on a machine...

Comment: @mlwn I run in Bash shell; compile with `g++ -std=c++11 file.cpp`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [point of difference between C++03 and C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get#Notes):

> #### Notes
>
> In C++98/C++03, if an error occurs, `v` is left unchanged. In C++11, it is set to a value as described above.

In C++11, on failure to extract an `int` the target is set to `0`.

Note that even if your compiler is set to C++03 mode it may still be exhibiting the C++11 behaviour, for example if its standard library does not bother to adopt the old behavior in C++03 mode.